# Modified double slit, slanting

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Would it matter if the slits are positioned at different distance away from the source?
Case 1: Shuts Slit A(nearest slit) after assuming particle should reach it by then.

Case 2: Shuts Slit B after assuming particle should reach it by then.

Case 3: shuts Slit B after assuming particle should reach Slit A by then.

Case 4: shuts Slit A after assuming particle should reach Slit B by then.

Note at no point throughout the experiment is the particle being measured/detected.

Comment: Hmm Definitely sounds interesting but I'm not very sure what you mean.  For instance "without doing any measurement".

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs: I mean relying on timing instead of trapdoor which activates when it detects(measure) something going thru.

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion of this type of question over the past century. The upshot is that if you do something that makes it possible to determine which path the particle took - then it acts like a particle (no interference). For example, see the literature on the delayed choice experiments, which seem similar to your specific question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser

Comment: The question is not clear.  Are you asking what the diffraction pattern will look like?  Of course it's not possible to know what the diffraction pattern "looks like" without some sort of measurement of the pattern.

Comment: @S.McGrew: I am trying to see at which point in time the particle interact with itself without actually measuring directly which path

Comment: OK, another clarification is needed.  For example in Case 1, is the slit shut before or after the particle is expected to pass through the slit?

Comment: @S.McGrew: Slit A should shut immediately once the time expected for particle to reach it lapsed. Any earlier is meaningless I believe right?

Answer (score 0):

If a slit is shuttered *before* the particle is expected to have passed through, no interference pattern will appear.

If the slit is shuttered *after* the particle has had enough time to have passed through, the interference pattern will appear same as if there had been no shutter.